# When phone is off and I plug it in to outlet the phone turns on instead of charging

Tags: charging

This might be hardware but I'm not sure so thought I'd ask.

Went to plug in to charger at home last night - noticed it didn't charge. Wake up in the morning though and the battery hadn't dropped (or raised)

At work I have a different charger and same thing seems to be happening.

I powered off my phone though, removed battery, put back in, and plugged in. This is where it gets strange - instead of showing me a large battery charging which is what use to occur it turns on immediately.

I checked Software Updates and everything is up-to-date. It is a **Samsung Infuse**.

*update*

WHILE PLUGGED IN:

Entered * # * # 4 6 3 6 # * #* to display battery info:

- Battery Status: Not charging
- Power plug: Unplugged
- Battery level: 63%
- Battery scale: 100
- Battery health: Good
- Battery voltage: 3810 mV
- Battery temperature: 28.0 deg C
- Time since boot: 11:50

Comment: what phone is it? I have heard of some Motorola phones doing this.

Comment: @RyanConrad A Samsung Infuse (see the last 2 words of your namesake's question).

Comment: @Izzy Not sure how i missed that...

Comment: made the phone bold for you and added some more info

Comment: @Ryan: Have you tried any other cables? Also, are you using the AC adapter that came with the phone?

Comment: Yes I tried with other cables. Tried bringing it to ATT only to have them say the Infuse is longer supported. Wound up buying a battery and a wall charger and just have to charge the battery outside of the phone and have been using Blutooth/Email for any data transfers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What sticks out to me is that your battery status says "Not charging" Instead of discharging. I feel like your phone may recognize that the charger is plugged in, but may have some error in the battery/phone itself. I feel like your phone may just be translating the charger power directly into the phone itself, and is not able to charge the battery. If this is the case, it IS a hardware issue. Sorry that there isn't much you can do.

Comment: At this point I've bought a wall charger and second battery and have been swapping. I'll leave the question though so if anyone does have an actual solution.